# In C, How to get capturing group RegEx?

Tags: c, regex

This is the C function I am having problems with:

```
char get_access_token(char *client_credentials)
{
    regex_t regex;
    int reti;
    char msgbuf[100];
    reti = regcomp(&regex, "\\\"access_token\\\".\\\"(.*?)\\\"", 0);

    regmatch_t pmatch[1];
    if (reti) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    reti = regexec(&regex, client_credentials, 1, pmatch, 0);
    if (!reti) {
        puts("Match");
    } else if (reti == REG_NOMATCH) {
        puts("No match");
    } else {
        regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
        fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
        exit(1);
    }

    return (char) "";
}
```

The string that I'm trying to parse is a JSON string, I don't care about the actual structure I only care about the access token.

It should look like this:

`{"access_token": "blablablabal"}`

I want my function to return just "blablablabla"

The RegEx that I'm trying to use is this one:

`\"access_token"."(.*?)"`

but I can't find that in the variable `pmatch`, I only find two numbers in that array, I don't really know what those numbers mean.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I'm a C noob, I'm just learning.

Answer (score 1):

There's several problems. You have typos in your regex. And you're trying to use extended regex features with a POSIX regex.

First the typos.

```
reti = regcomp(&regex, "\\\"access_token\\\".\\\"(.*?)\\\"", 0);
                                            ^
```

That should be:

```
reti = regcomp(&regex, "\\\"access_token\\\": \\\"(.*?)\\\"", 0);
```

Then we don't need to escape quotes in regexes. That makes it easier to read.

```
reti = regcomp(&regex, "\"access_token\": \"(.*?)\"", 0);
```

This still doesn't work because it's using features that basic POSIX regexes do not have. Capture groups must be escaped in a basic POSIX regex. This can be fixed by using `REG_EXTENDED`. The `*?` non-greedy operators is an enhanced non-POSIX feature borrowed from Perl. You get them with `REG_ENHANCED`.

```
reti = regcomp(&regex, "\"access_token\": \"(.*?)\"", REG_ENHANCED|REG_EXTENDED);
```

---

But don't try to parse JSON with a regex for all the same reasons [we don't parse HTML with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use a JSON library such as [json-glib](https://developer.gnome.org/json-glib/stable/JsonParser.html).

Comment: I tried using the library, but then again, I was running into another sort of issues. That's why I thought it was going to be easier to just parse JSON. Although I'm not a beginner developer, I'm very much a noob with C, so having troubles with it.

Comment: @ILikeTacos C is unforgiving. I imagine you might have had some trouble with shared libraries. Maybe try out json-glib and ask a question if you run into trouble.

Comment: I did have a lot of trouble with shared libraries, but I figured it out. All I needed to do was to pass the path to the library to the linker, but I banged my head against the wall for a few seconds. I'll probably be spamming SO with questions about json-glib as soon as i finish installing it.

Comment: @ILikeTacos `pkg-config` can save you a lot of headaches when it comes to linking libraries.

Comment: I think the code could replace the occurrences of `\\\"` with just `\"`. Within the regexes, a double quote isn't special (not a metacharacter) and doesn't need a backslash escape.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your `pmatch` array must have at least **two** elements, as you probably know, group 0 is the whole matching regexp, and it is filled for the whole regexp (like if all the regular expression were rounded by a pair of parenthesis) you want group 1, so `pmatch[1]` will be filled with the information of the first subexpression group.

If you look in the doc, the `pmatch` element has two fields that index the beginning index in the original buffer where the group was matched, and the *one past the last* index of the place in the string where the group ends.  These field names are `rm_so` and `rm_eo`, and like the ones in `pmatch[0]`, they indicate the index at where the regular (sub)expression begins and ends, resp.

You can print the matched elements with (once you know that they are valid, see doc) with:

```
#define SIZEOF(arr) (sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0])
...
regmatch_t pmatch[2]; /* for global regexp and group 1 */
...
/* you don't need to escape " chars, they are not special for regcomp,
 * they do, however, for C, so only one \ must be used. */
res = regcomp(&regex, "\"access_token\".\"([^)]*)\"", 0);
...
reti = regexec(&regex, client_credentials, SIZEOF(pmatch), pmatch, 0);

for (i = 0; i < regex.re_nsub; i++) {
    char *p = client_credentials + pmatch[i].rm_so; /* p points to beginning of match */
    size_t l = pmatch[i].rm_eo - pmatch[i].rm_so; /* match length */
    printf("Group #%d: %0.*s\n", i, l, p);
}
```

My apologies for submitting a snippet of code instead of a verifiable and complete example, but as you didn't do it in the question (so we could not test your sample code) I won't do in the answer.  So, the code is not tested, and can have errors on my side.  Beware of this.

Testing a sample response requires time, worse if we have first to make your sample code testable at all.  (this is a complaint about the beginners ---and some nonbeginners--- use of not posting [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).